# Why does richfaces 4.5.1 show components' IDs together with the label?

Tags: java, html, xhtml, richfaces

I'm migrating a microservice from Richfaces 3.3 to 4.5.1 and I have this strange problem:

when using a component like `<rich:accordion id="menu" label="Menu">` I have no errors, but when the element is rendered I find this in the component instead of the label: `j_idt73:menu` or, in another case, `bodyForm:j_idt17`.

The strange thing here is that some other components are well rendered (for example inside that "accordion" tag up above I'm using a `<rich:tree>` and all is ok.

EDIT:

this only happens with the `<rich:accordion> tag`.

Thank you all

Comment: I don't quite get what your issue is but `rich:accordion` doesn't have a "label" attribute. Can you show the code that you expect to see?

Comment: Hi @Makhiel, you got the point. The problem was the label attribute. I inherited this very old code and since this attribute was non-blocking I thought it was ok. Thank you!